# How to access body data (event payload) of webhook request in Jenkins using Bitbucket Branch Source plugin?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, bitbucket-server

I am using the Bitbucket Branch Source plugin in Jenkins to manage mutlibranch repos in projects. Bitbucket is configured to send a post webhook to a generic Jenkins url: https://JENKINS_URL/bitbucket-scmsource-hook/notify. This triggers a build of the Jenkinsfile pipeline that's in the repo.

I want to be able to access the event payload of the webhook request in order to tell if this trigger was from a branch creation, deletion, or modification event. If I point the webhook to a dummy endpoint, I can see the data that I want to access in the body of the request.

I am using Jenkins 2.112 and Bitbucket Server 5.14

I have tried outputting all of the environment variables in the Jenkinsfile using:

```
echo sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'env')
```

But the event payload is not one of the variables.

I have seen this similar question here: 
[Accessing the BitBucket webhook's payload in Jenkins jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33548769/accessing-the-bitbucket-webhooks-payload-in-jenkins-jobs)
but I am using a slightly different plugin.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?

Comment: nope, it would probably take a feature request from the bitbucket plugin or something.